# Is it possible to create a dependency graph using the architecture explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, architecture

VS2010 has got an option in the Architecture menu called "Create dependency graph".

It works great except it seems to be all or nothing - all solution items end up in that graph and its very slow for our large solution.

I want to create a dependency graph by class, whose root is only a single class that I specify.

Is it possible to create a query (DGQL) in the architecture explorer that emulates the "Create dependency graph" but where I can specify the root class?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the flexibility of the tool NDepend to [generate dependency graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx) you are asking for. *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

> I want to create a dependency graph by class, whose root is only a single class that I specify.

If your need is to visualize a graph made of types that use a class *C*, and then types that use these users types, and so on transitively... with NDepend you just need to ask for users types, and then export the result to a graph as [explained here](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx#Call).

Here is a large call graph generated by NDepend (the [full size version is available here](http://www.ndepend.com/Res/DiagramBoxAndArrowGraphBig.jpg)):

[image: call graph]

> all solution items end up in that graph and its very slow for our large solution.

With NDepend graph, most of your graphs operations will be instantaneous, even if you are working with a very large code base.